# Does Lego Indiana Jones come with a CD key?

Tags: pc, lego-indiana-jones

I recently noticed a second hand copy of Lego Indiana Jones 1 and 2 on sale and was wondering if anyone knows if the retail version of the game comes with a one-time or limited use CD/activation key.

This is in regards to the PC versions of the games (not the Steam versions).

I am not asking for a CD key, but rather is the second hand copy useless for a new owner/restricted to the original purchaser?

Comment: I don't know why you are voted down, because that is a good question.

Comment: If someone could clarify the downvotes I can amend the question.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The unboxing videos for both the [first (mute is your friend here)](https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=4wVmkQm9NJ4) and [second game](https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=R3n-ZWWr2Lo#?t=4m01s) don't show any CD-Key, but both games use [SecuROM protection](http://forum.daemon-tools.cc/gamedb.php?letter=L). This means you may have trouble or be unable to install the game if you buy it used. SecuROM can be a simple as only verifying a disc is inserted, or as complex as tying an activation to the hardware to limit the number of installs. There doesn't seem to be any indication online about which types these games employ. That said, there does seem to be people selling and buying used copies and I don't see any reviews or reports of being unable to play it.

Comment: Googling lists of games that do online activation with SecuRom appears to omit Lego games completely.  Also, I appreciate the method of checking unboxing videos.

Comment: @rasteve Yeah, that's what I was seeing too, but I didn't see anywhere that said it didn't explicitly. Also, that's what I usually do for these types of things :)

Comment: In addition, SecuRom errors for the games in question only show errors regarding using virtual drives.